# Greasemonkey script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, greasemonkey

Here is the full Greasemonkey script to remove a model screen/page that pops-up or blocks the actual web content when the adblocker is enabled in firefox. But its not removing the model screen.

/**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


if (document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName('tbox')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

**/

However when the modal page pop-up and if I open the "Web Developer > Web Console" and execute these lines

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName('tbox')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

It works i.e it removes the modal webpage and lets me read the web contents.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var interval;

function go()
{
     if (document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0]) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('tmask')[0].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName('tbox')[0].style.display = 'none';
        clearInterval(interval);
     }
}

window.addEventListener( 'load', function( event )
{
    if( window.top == window.self ) //don't run in frames
    {
        interval = setInterval( go, 500 );
    }
}, false );
```

My guess is you're not waiting for the page to load, thus your script runs before 'tmask' actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I tried that it did not work. Similar cases can be found on quora forums...go to this URL "https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Landmark-Forum-like-I%E2%80%99ve-heard-it%E2%80%99s-everything-from-a-cult-to-the-most-transformative-experience-ever" then click on any of the URL on the right side bar "Related Questions" the sign-in diaglog pop up.

Comment: I don't have an account so your link isn't of any use for me. Try the edit above, which delays execution by 1s as a test, if the popup is generated after load. Have you ensured that the tag exists at run time?

Comment: Might want to consider using _setInterval_ instead to check for the element periodically and then clear the interval when the element is present and the function was executed.

Comment: Yup that worked, I increase the interval to 1000 - thank you so much to both of you.

Comment: Glad to help! This is a common issue with a lot of user scripts. Waiting for the page to load or adding events to the elements directly is usually the best way to avoid premature running of a script. Please mark this answer and/or press the up arrow so others may gain insight from your question in the future :)